# Deserializer String data time using Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to deserializer the following date time String **'6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM'** using annotation like that:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
@JsonProperty("DateModified") 
private LocalDateTime dateModified;

  {
    "XXXX": "....",
    "XXXX1": "....",
    "DateModified": "6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM",
```

But getting the following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type 
`java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM": Failed to deserialize 
java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Any idea what I am missing ?

Thank you

Comment: The `@JsonFormat.pattern` uses `-` while the json date uses `/`.

Comment: I did try that. Same error. It used to work in the past I am not sure if the issue is coming from the file.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Answer (score 1):

The problem stands in your `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format for which your `"6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM"` results invalid so you have to do three changes to it to parse your string date :

1. change `-` with `/`.
2. you exchanged days with months because `18` is surely a day of the month so your pattern should start with `M/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy`.
3. your hours are from 1 to 12 because the presence of `PM` so you have to use `h` instead of `H` for hours and adding the `a` at the end of your pattern for the `AM/PM` case.

So one valid pattern for the `"6/18/2021 5:25:57 PM"` string date is the `"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"` pattern, you can check the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) page for more detailed explanations.